# Proof that $i\cot(t/2) = (1 + \alpha) / (1 - \alpha)$ where $\alpha = \cos t + i\sin t$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I am reviewing complex analysis revision problems and I am stuck on this trigonometric solution to the identity. Can anyone give me a hint as to what steps I should follow.

I have to show the following.
Suppose $\alpha = \cos(t) + isin(t)$ where $0<t<2\pi$. Show that

$ \frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha} = i \cot(\frac{t}{2})$.

I have tried expanding cot into exponential form and then playing with the algebra but I have had no luck. I have tried similar technique on the other side. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Write $\beta=\cos(t/2)+i\sin(t/2)$, and use
$$\beta^2=\alpha,$$
$$\beta+\beta^{-1}=2\cos(t/2),$$
$$\beta-\beta^{-1}=2i\sin(t/2).$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\;\displaystyle 1+\cos t = 2 \cos^2 \frac{t}{2}\,$, $\,\displaystyle1-\cos t = 2 \sin^2 \frac{t}{2}\,$ and $\,\displaystyle  \sin t = 2 \sin \frac {t}{2} \, \cos \frac{t}{2}\,$.

Answer (score 0):

$\alpha = e^{it}$

so

$ \frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha} = \frac{ e^{\frac{it}{2}} +e^{ \frac{-it}{2} } }{e^{ \frac{it}{2} }-e^{ \frac{-it}{2} }}$

Also, $e^{ix} + e^{-ix} =2\cos x $ , $e^{ix} - e^{-ix} =2i\sin x $

so $ \frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha} = \frac{ e^{\frac{it}{2}} +e^{ \frac{-it}{2} } }{e^{ \frac{it}{2} }-e^{ \frac{-it}{2} }}= i\cot \frac{t}{2}$